# How to solve Ajax Forbidden 403 - GD

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();


jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "processa.php",
data: dados,
success: function( data )
{
$('#imagem').attr("src",data);
}
});


return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 


// FORM 


<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form"> 
   Title <input type = "text" name="titulo" value="">
    X <input type = "text" name="x" value="">
    Y <input type = "text" name="y" value=""> 
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>


// Here I am trying to print the updated image
<img id="imagem" src="<?php $texto?>.jpg">
</body>


</html>
```

file processa.php

```
  <?php


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
 $x = $_POST['x'];
 $y = $_POST['y'];


}


// Generate image using the GD library
$texto = $titulo; // content from post form
$font_size = 10; 
$font_file = 'arial.ttf'; 
$texto = wordwrap($texto, 11, "\n", true);
 $x = $x; // has the form
 $y = $y; // has the form
 $imagem = imagecreate(50, 50); 
$fundo= imagecolorallocate($imagem , 0, 0, 0); 
$letra= imagecolorallocate($imagem , 255, 255, 255); 


imagettftext($imagem, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $letra, $font_file, $texto);
 imagejpeg($imagem, $texto.".jpg", 100); // saved image directory 
imagedestroy($imagem); 
echo $texto.".jpg";
?>
```

In processa.php file should create an image with the title and padding X and Y values reported in the form.

The file name is the same title.

in Google Chrome console, after clicking on submit takes about 30 seconds and appears forbidden 403, and the location where the image should appear in the source code changes to the same console error but summarized:

```
<img id="imagem" src="<br /> <font size='1'<table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' bor...eeec'>..\processa.php<b>:</b>76</td></tr>
</table></font>
test.jpg">
```

test.jpg is what was stated in the titulo field. But the GD image is not generated.

I tried to resolve the error forbidden in entering .htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^site\/?$ /site/form.php [NC,L]  
 RewriteRule ^site\/?$ /site/processa.php [NC,L]   // entering this
```

But so far not got a solution

thank help

---

EDIT

**Put the full path in ajax even being in the same folder. This solved the problem. Thanks user @Dagon**

Comment: can you access processa.php directly?

Comment: processa.php this in the same directory that form.php and other files all have the same permissions

Comment: so if you put it in your browser it returns what?

Comment: Returns: Notice: Undefined variable: titulo Notice: Undefined variable: x Notice: Undefined variable: y   and  ../uploads/imagens/.jpg

Comment: if your not getting a 403 directly, you shouldent via ajax, sure your hitting the right file

Comment: It worked thank you, put the full path in ajax even being in the same folder. But the X and Y variables are not getting the form data

Comment: your not sending them in the ajax request

Comment: var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();  takes all fields of the form?